# Where does turtlebot3_core define odom and base_footprint names?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am attempting to run slam gmapping for 2 robots. I am having a problem where the transform trees are conjoining instead of there being 2 separate trees.  **I have already included namespaces and tf_prefixes in all of the launch files.** odom and base_footprint are both generated after launching turtlebot3_core, and I cannot for the life of me find where these names are defined. Where can I change the names of these generated tf nodes? Or is there another way I can manage this? [image: a closeup of the issues in view_frames]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299330/where-does-turtlebot3_core-define-odom-and-base_footprint-names?/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

TurtleBot3 was updated last month.
For now it provides simple way for loading multiple robot.
You can find the way how to figure it out.

https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-turtlebot3-software-v1-0-0-and-firmware-v1-2-0-update/4888/6

http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/applications/#load-multiple-turtlebot3s

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-01**:
@Darby Lim instead of only providing links to the resources, can you please update your question with a copy and paste of some minimal example? If and when these links disappear (which happens often) then your answer will lose its value and won't be self-contained.

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-08-01**:
Wow, further reading has shown that this update takes care of exactly the problem I am having! Thank you so much for the help!

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-08-01**:
@jayess Sorry, I will add some examples next answers :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-01**:
@Darby Lim No problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi AmateurHour,

I was looking for that too, finally I found it is defined in `"OpenCR"` instead of `"Raspberry pi"`, so you can't find them in the node: `"turtlebot3_core"` launched by `"turtlebot3_core.launch"`.

If you want to see the code, it is [here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/tree/master/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/examples/turtlebot3_waffle/turtlebot3_core), if you want to edit anything or change topics, you need to install Arduino by following [this](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencr10/#arduino-ide), then you will see the code in [examples](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/opencr_setup/).

But your real issue is trying to launch two robots for SLAM, maybe you can try [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/282060/how-to-have-multi-turtlebot-3-in-a-real-environment/).

---

Originally posted by [JadenLin](https://answers.ros.org/users/44014/jadenlin/) with karma: 31 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3